# Using different array-types interchangeably

Tags: c++

I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere, but I'm not sure, what to even search for:

Say I have a class that stores some data in a `std::vector`, but I want to be able to use two differenct types interchangeably (for example to save memory) depending on the "mode" I set the class to. Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    int Mode; // Could be, say, 0 or 1
    std::vector<float> MyData; // Use this when Mode is 0
    std::vector<short> MyData; // Use this when Mode is 1

    void DoStuffWithData()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I know, this could probably be done with `template`, but I have not yet managed to wrap my head around this (if anybody could give me an example, please do so). Of course I could work with overloaded functions and use a lot of if-statements to switch between the cases or use a void-pointer that is set to one of the `vectors` and then cast to its type, but I think, this would make pretty messy code.

What would be a nice and clean way to use (mostly) the same code by just referring to `MyData`?

**Edit**

Mode would change during runtime. Basically the class would record and work with data it collects in the background. I want to be able to just change `Mode` for a new "recording" (of which I might start multiple during runtime). This would then set both `vectors` to size zero and use the one selected. Again - I know, I could overload functions and just use some if-statements, but I would like to keep the code short and clean (and maybe learn some things along the way).

Comment: the way you wrote it you are using more memory not less. Templates is maybe the way to go. Depends on how and when you decide what `Mode` should be. Does this happen at runtime or compiletime?

Comment: Mode would change during compiletime (and the class would not be deleted and created new). And of course I would set the size of the `vector` not in use to zero to save memory. Can you give me an example of how to do this with templates?

Comment: Sorry, typo - I meant the Mode would change during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two members called `MyData`. You can use templates instead, as that's essentially what they're meant for. This would be a simple example:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
    std::vector<T> MyData;
    void DoStuffWithData()
    {
        // ...
    }
};


int main() {
    MyClass<short> shortData;
    MyClass<float> floatData;
    MyClass<long> longData; // you're no longer limited to just two types
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Notice there's no `Mode` anymore, as you'll just choose the desired type when declaring each variable.

Comment: The two members called `MyData` were just an example to illustrate what I want to do. As I understand your solution, I couldn't change the class from `short` to `float`. This would create a new instance. But I would like to change the used type during runtime within the same instance

Comment: @PaulAner in the comment above you reply that Mode is selected at compile time, now you say it is runtime. Please clarify, perhaps by adding an example of how you would use the class and how you want to select / switch the mode

Comment: Sorry, typo - I meant the Mode would change during runtime.